# collection of value object mapping error

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying To map object field in **fluent-Nhibernate** and **C#**,the model contain an entity which has a reference field to a `ValueObject`,

this is the entity class

```
public class QueryLeaf : Entity
{
    public QueryLeaf()
    {
        FilterDescriptors = new List<FilterDescriptor>();
    }
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<FilterDescriptor> FilterDescriptors { get; set; }
}
```

this is the value object class

```
[Serializable]
public class FilterDescriptor : ValueObject
{
    public FilterOperator FilterOperator { get; set; }//this is an enum value
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the mapping class

```
public sealed class QueryLeafMap : ClassMap<QueryLeaf>
{
    public QueryLeafMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);    
        HasMany(x => x.FilterDescriptors).Component(com =>
        {
            com.Map(y => y.FilterOperator);
            com.Map(y => y.Value);
        });
    }
}
```

When running the above code the compiler stops on `global.asax` page and give me this error

> collection element mapping has wrong number of columns
>   QueryLeaf.FilterDescriptors type: component[FilterOperator,Value]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general we can map *Reference* types with `.References()` and *Value* types with a `.Map()`. The **`object`** is for sure reference type, and is causing this kind of problem.

In fact, we cannot map `object`, it is too genaral. We should create some custom type (class) or map a general value to its serialized or, if possible, **to string value**.

So this small change would make the above code working:

```
[Serializable]
public class FilterDescriptor : ValueObject
{
    public FilterOperator FilterOperator { get; set; }//this is an enum value
    // cannot map object
    // public object Value { get; set; }
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
    // and we can do some magic later
    public object Value { get { ... use the StringValue } ... }
}
```

And because we used different name this should be the new mapping

```
HasMany(x => x.FilterDescriptors).Component(com =>
{
    com.Map(y => y.FilterOperator);
    //com.Map(y => y.Value);
    com.Map(y => y.StringValue);
});
```